# How i can get static value with the pound symbol?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign pound value for input box. I am getting error
can u please help me? if i give alert means its showing the value but i cant see the input value in inputbox
I have tried below code

```
var valchrCode = String.fromCharCode('163');
var abc = valchrCode + 30;
document.getElementById("mrp30ppm").value = abc;
alert(abc );
```

Comment: show html code also

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript code is executed before the input field is to the page you will get the null exception error.

Make you that the element exists when you use

`document.getElementById("mrp30ppm").value`

You can use `window.onload` or `$(document).ready function(` (if you want to use jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Code is working.Please check input field have id like below and jQuery library included for this particular page.

Check console if any error post in your question.

```
<input id="mrp30ppm" type="text" name="" />

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var valchrCode = String.fromCharCode('163');
var abc = valchrCode + 30;
document.getElementById("mrp30ppm").value = abc;
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: i have tried same but i cant see the value of inputbox

Comment: Have you check console log? any error there

Comment: Yes, I have checked I didnt get any error